# How to insert list of integers into a string for a database query - Python 3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, psycopg2

I am trying to use the cursor execute to make a query in a django application, but when I pass the list into the query string it comes with quotation marks and returns the following error:

> psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "139,212,933,2303,2613"
>   LINE 1: ...ados_ibge.sociodemografia_rmc sd WHERE sd.gid IN ('139,212,9...

This is the code ive been working on so far..

```
gids = self.request.GET.getlist('gid')

if gids:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:

        g = ','.join(gids)
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM poi.farmacias_rmc f, dados_ibge.sociodemografia_rmc sd WHERE sd.gid IN (%s) AND ST_Intersects(sd.geom, f.geom) = true", [g])

        rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: What is the value of `gids`?

Comment: g = ','.join(str(gids)) <--- try this.

Comment: Instead of passing a list [g] have you tried string i.e. g, coz the query with in operator is like SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ids in (1, 3, 6, 7, 9)

Answer (score 1):

You should not convert the list `gids` to a string, but to a tuple :

```
cursor.execute(""" 
    SELECT * FROM poi.farmacias_rmc f, dados_ibge.sociodemografia_rmc sd 
      WHERE sd.gid IN %s 
      AND ST_Intersects(sd.geom, f.geom) = true
    """, [tuple(gids)])
```

Python lists are automatically converted to SQL Arrays, and tuples are converted to SQL lists.